# Stop notification for google watch when token is expired

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

Here is the situation.

User is connected to our application and we have authenticated him with google calendar to start Watch for any event on his calendar.
We have stared getting the event notification but now User access token is expired and we are not sure when user will re-authenticated him self with our app.
But we are still getting the notifications, which we want to stop, but we are unable to stop the Watch because his access token is expired.

**Is there any way we can stop the Watch with above mention scenario?**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The notifications should stop automatically in expiration time. You can choose to stop receiving notifications for a particular channel before it expires by calling the stop method at the following URI:

`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop`

This method requires that you provide at least the channel’s `id` and the `resourceId` properties, as shown in the example below.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop
Authorization: Bearer {auth_token_for_current_user}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66",
  "resourceId": "ret08u3rv24htgh289g"
}
```

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#stopping-notifications) on how to stop notifications.

Comment: Thanks for reply...   But my question is...  i am unable to stop the Watch because my access token is expired.     Could you please send me the C# code to stop notification.